# Counting emails in gmail with google apps script - for loop limits to 500 iterations

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am developing a small app to run inbox analytics on gmail.  The gmail account I am using is a paid google apps account.

All is working well except that when counting for certain statistics with google apps script, if the count exceeds 500 the for loop stops and returns 500.

Is that a limitation of google apps script's looping? Is there anyway to increase the iterator limitation is so?

Below is the code

```
var DAYS_TO_SEARCH = 10; // look only in sent messages from last 7 days, otherwise script takes a while
var SINGLE_MESSAGE_ONLY = false; // exclude multi-message conversations where I sent the last message? 
var NO_REPLY = 0;

function label_messages_without_response() {
  var emailAddress = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log(emailAddress);
  var EMAIL_REGEX = /[a-zA-Z0-9\._\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-z\.A-Z]+/g;
  var label = GmailApp.createLabel("AwaitingResponse");
  var d = new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - DAYS_TO_SEARCH);
  var dateString = d.getFullYear() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate();
  threads = GmailApp.search("in:Sent after:" + dateString);
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
  {
    var thread = threads[i];
    if (!SINGLE_MESSAGE_ONLY || thread.getMessageCount() == 1)
    {
      var lastMessage = thread.getMessages()[thread.getMessageCount()-1];
      lastMessageSender = lastMessage.getFrom().match(EMAIL_REGEX)[0];
      if (lastMessageSender == emailAddress)
      {
      NO_REPLY ++;
      Logger.log(NO_REPLY);


      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log("FINAL REPLY RATE:" + NO_REPLY);
}
```

Example output:

```
[16-11-26 19:59:35:548 PST] 497.0
[16-11-26 19:59:35:601 PST] 498.0
[16-11-26 19:59:35:652 PST] 499.0
[16-11-26 19:59:35:652 PST] FINAL REPLY RATE:499
```

If more then one day is calculated the FINAL REPLY RATES is always 499.  However when I calculated just one day the result was 386, it seems anything exceeding 499 is not calculated.

Note * I'm sending between 300 and 700 emails a day from this account.

Much thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with a large ammount of emails you may be better off using the Gmail API instead. I have a script that fetches all emails between a start and end date and outputs the receive date, recipient, sender and title into a spreadsheet.

```
queriedMessages =
      Gmail.Users.Messages.list(userInfo.mail, {
        'q': queryString,
        'pageToken': execProperties.nextPageId
      });
```

That will get all individual messages, based on your `queryString` which is what you would enter into the Gmail search box, so you can use labels etc. (check [advanced search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) for options). See the API reference [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/). After a quick look, you may want to also use `Gmail.Users.Threads.list` instead. Check on it [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list). It seems to work the same way `Messages` did (I needed separate messages as opposed to threads).

You will only get 1 page of threads/messages at once (which is 100), however you also get a next page token with the theads/messages, which you can then use as `'pageToken':` to aim at the next page where in my code `execProperties.nextPageId = queriedMessages.nextPageToken` as obviously on the first go you will not have a `nextPageId`.

I would also recommend to set up a timeout procedure, as I found you will easily go over 6 minutes by getting large amounts of emails. What I do is have it check how long on average a loop takes to execute and if I have less time left (I use a 5 minute mark just in case) to do 1 more execution, I store everything in script properties, set up a trigger for 1 minute later and then terminate the script. That's why you see `execProperties.nextPageId`, because I might just have it from the previous execution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the maximum threads you can get is 500, as a check you can try something like:

```
function threads (){
 var threads = GmailApp.search("in:Sent"); 
  Logger.log(threads.length);
}
```

The log will show 500 even if you have more.

The solution would be to do it in batches of 500:

```
threads = GmailApp.search("in:Sent after:" + dateString, start, max);
```

Note max in above cannot be greater than 500.